# AsyncTask kills my app when I execute ProgressDialog.show() method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

The title is clearly. When I launch AsyncTask my app crash. Exactly the problem is in the ProgressDialog's show method.

I launch my AsncTask from a Fragment (onCreate method).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    context = getActivity().getBaseContext();

                LoadLastNewAsync llna = new LoadLastNewAsync(context, lang);

                try {
                    tituloAviso = llna.execute().get();

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
}
```

This is mi AsyncTask code:

```
public class LoadLastNewAsync extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
    Context context;
    private DataBaseHelper myDbHelper;
    private String tituloAviso;
    private Aviso aviso;
    private String lang;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog; 


    //constructor
     public LoadLastNewAsync(Context context, String lang) {
            //mActivity = activity;
         this.context = context;
         this.lang = lang;
        }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);//erabiltzaileak atzera botoia sakatuz ez kantzelatzeko
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);//barrarewn estiloa. Espiral bat izango da
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);


    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("Testing", "LoadLastNewAsync. Entra en doInBackGround");
        myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(context);
        boolean dbExist = myDbHelper.checkDataBase();
        if(dbExist){
            aviso = new Aviso();
            aviso = recuperarUltimoAviso();
            tituloAviso = aviso.getTitle();
        }

        return tituloAviso; 

    }

    private Aviso recuperarUltimoAviso() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
            aviso = myDbHelper.getUltimoAviso(this.lang);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        myDbHelper.close();
        return aviso;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

I receive this log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.kirolm.instalacionesdep, PID: 29441
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kirolm.instalacionesdep/com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.Main}: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:536)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:259)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:286)
at com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.asynctask.LoadLastNewAsync.onPreExecute(LoadLastNewAsync.java:41)
at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
at com.kirolm.instalacionesdep.HomeFragment.onCreate(HomeFragment.java:71)
at android.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1678)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:859)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5240)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
```

I don't know where is the problem. It is maybe in the context? of the problem is in the Fragment cycle live?

Comment: First, never use a bare dialog, as it does not handle configuration changes, and so you will crash when the user rotates the screen, puts the device in a desk dock, changes locale, etc. Use a `DialogFragment` or otherwise handle the activity lifecycle. Second, never use methods like `getBaseContext()` unless you know **exactly why** you are using those methods. `Activity` itself is a `Context`; use it.

Comment: I can't agree with you ... first should be: never use AsyncTask.get, it makes AsyncTask useless ... the real problem is that UI thread do not leave onCreate ... so in fact the Activity itself is not fully created ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ProgressDialog` needs the activity context for the displaying it.Try to replace the `AsyncTask` declaration as

```
 LoadLastNewAsync llna = new LoadLastNewAsync(getActivity(), lang);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot display an application window/dialog through a Context that is not an Activity. Try passing a valid activity reference.

Answer (score 0):

Use current activity context instead of base context **MyActivity.this** **as context** before pass it through constructor

also use progress dialog in onPost of async task as

```
try{
    if (pWindow != null) {
       pWindow.dismiss();
    } 
} catch (IllegalStateException ise) {
        ise.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your onPreExecute method. Try this,it worked for me.
Replace

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
```

with

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getDialogContext());
```

Define getDialogContext() method as:

```
private Context getDialogContext()
{
    Context context;
    if (getParent() != null)
        context = getParent();
    else
        context = this;
    return context;
}
```